# Append data from 1 file to another using AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I have an already existing script to check the exclusive data between 2 files and load it in 3rd file. The command is below.

```
var='FNR == NR {keys[$1 $2]; next} !($1 $2 in keys)'
awk -F\| $var file1.dat file2.dat > file3.dat
```

The requirement is to reuse the same but just append the data from file2 to file3 ignoring file1. I tried to do the below but it is spooling the data from both file1 and file2. All I need is, though there are 2 file names provided in the awk command, only the 2nd file data to be appended.

```
var='{print $0}'
awk -F\| $var file1.dat file2.dat > file3.dat
```

Can anyone help with the exact command.
Below is the data in each file and expected output.

File1 (Can have 0 or more) - We should not look at this file at all

```
123
456
789
```

File2:

```
123
ABC
XYZ
456
```

Expected output in File3 (All from file2 and just ignore file1 input, but I have to have the file1 name in awk command)

```
123
ABC
XYZ
456
```

Comment: `file1
123`

`file2
456`

Expected output: 
File3 (All contents from file2).. Though File1 is present in the command, it should be ignored.
456

Comment: @Sandeep, But I am just wondering why you are passing it on first place? Is it really needed to get first file1 name pass to `awk`? Just curios to ask here.

Comment: Regarding `keys[$1 $2]` - you can't in general concatenate 2 strings to come up with a unique string since `a bc` and `ab c` both concatenate to `abc`. That's why `SUBSEP` exists. Though it'll work if the substrings are always the same length, it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: while you've mentioned it in a couple comments, you may want to update the question to include some details about your real world requirements (ie, number of files, sizes of files - #rows, MBytes) as this kind of info lets us know that performance is going to play a (big) part in the final solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All from `file2` and just ignore `file1` input, but I have to have the file1 name in awk command.

If you must use `file1` and `file2` in arguments to awk command and want to output content from `file2` only then you can just use:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {delete ARGV[1]} 1' file1 file2 > file3

123
ABC
XYZ
456
```

`delete ARGV[1]` will delete first argument from argument list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

I have 1800+ files to merge and 30K records in each file(it may increase further). I tried all the options provided by others and I see everything is running long. For 326 files to be merged, it has taken 12 minutes.

This command 'BEGIN {delete ARGV[1]} 1' had run 6 mins for all the files to be loaded. Yet to test with more data now. Please suggest if any kind of performance improvement can be done.

Comment: This would probably be the quickest of all the solutions and it would work with any awk version.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simply use `nextfile` to skip first Input_file named file1 itself and read 2nd file onwards.

```
awk 'NR==1{nextfile} 1' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, this awk command failed as invalid. Seems OS issue.

Comment: @U12, this requires GNU `awk`. Could you please do check your awk version by doing `awk -V` once?

Answer (score 0):

also remember not to waste time splitting unneeded fields

> ```
> {m,g}awk 'BEGIN { delete ARGV[_^=FS="^$"] }_' file1 file2
> ```

and it's ***MUUUCH*** faster not reading it a row at a time :

> ```
> mawk2 'BEGIN { delete ARGV[_^=FS="^$"] }_'             "${m2p}" "${m3t}"
> ```

```
 out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:01 [1.11GiB/s] [1.11GiB/s] [ <=>]
 f9d2e18d22eb58e5fc2173863cff238e  stdin
```

> ```
> mawk2 'BEGIN { delete ARGV[_^=RS=FS="^$"] }_^(ORS=__)' "${m2p}" "${m3t}"
> ```

```
 out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:00 [1.92GiB/s] [1.92GiB/s] [<=> ]
 f9d2e18d22eb58e5fc2173863cff238e  stdin
```

and try to avoid the slow default mode of `gawk` :

> ```
> gawk 'BEGIN { delete ARGV[_^=FS="^$"] }_'             "${m2p}" "${m3t}"
> ```

```
 out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:03 [ 620MiB/s] [ 620MiB/s] [ <=> ]
 f9d2e18d22eb58e5fc2173863cff238e  stdin
```